Set default value in laravel views filter
Default Filter Value Not Working in Laravel Views
I'm trying to add a default value to a filter in Laravel Views, but it's not working as expected. Here's my current implementation:
GruposActiveFilter class:
use LaravelViews\Filters\Filter;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class GruposActiveFilter extends Filter
{
    public function apply(Builder $query, $value, $request): Builder
    {
        return $query->where('Activo', $value);
    }

    public function options(): array
    {
        return [
            'Activo' => 1,
            'Inactivo' => 0,
        ];
    }
}

In my ListView:
protected function filters()
{
    return [
        new GruposActiveFilter,
    ];
}

What I've tried:
I've attempted to add a default() method to the filter class, but it doesn't seem to be recognized:
public function default()
{
    return 1;
}

Expected behavior:
I expect the filter to default to 'Activo' (value 1) when the page is first loaded.
Actual behavior:
The filter is not applying any default value, and I have to manually select a filter option each time.
How can I set a default value for my GruposActiveFilter in Laravel Views so that it's applied automatically when the page loads?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

have you tried returning the key instead of the value in your default method?
